# Azure B2C Custom Policies: How to disallow sending verification email to already verified email addresses (login with username)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a problem with Azure B2C and custom policies: I set B2C to use username instead of email address as explained in the example [username-signup-signin](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin).

My problem is that during the signup, the verification email can be sent to any email address, even to addresses that have been verified with another account.

My goal is to allow users to log in with their username and that their verification email address cannot be used to verify other accounts.

I have tried creating a custom verification email address control as specified in the example [pwd-reset-email-exists](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists) to check the passed email against `strongAuthenticationEmailAddress` without success.
I think the problem is the latter claim, but I don't know where to find the email address (which is not `signInNames.emailAddress`, since I use the username to log in).

To be clear, I need to check the **Email** property that is in **Authentication methods** in the user's tab in B2C.

**Verification control**

```xml
<DisplayControls>
    <DisplayControl Id="signupEmailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
        <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        </InputClaims>
        <DisplayClaims>
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" ControlClaimType="Email" Required="true" />
            <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
        </DisplayClaims>
        <Actions>
            <Action Id="SendCode">
                <ValidationClaimsExchange>
                    <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress" ContinueOnError="false" />
                    <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AadSspr-SendCode">
                        <Preconditions>
                            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
                                <Value>objectId</Value>
                                <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                            </Precondition>
                        </Preconditions>
                    </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
                </ValidationClaimsExchange>
            </Action>
            <Action Id="VerifyCode">
                <ValidationClaimsExchange>
                    <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AadSspr-VerifyCode" />
                </ValidationClaimsExchange>
            </Action>
        </Actions>
    </DisplayControl>
</DisplayControls>
```

**Technical profile**

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingStrongAuthenticationEmailAddress">
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided email.</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" Required="true" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />

        <!-- Optional claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having nearly the exact same problem.